# Twilio action for record

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm trying to create a Twilio workflow that places a call and records what the user says. For that I'm using `Record`, but I'm not entirely sure what to place in the `action` parameter.

Even though I understand Twilio will send information about the call to that URL, I don't necessarily require it. Is there a way to have some sort of a sinkhole for information?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Say voice="woman">Hi! Say your name:</Say>
<Record method="GET" action="URL_here" timeout="2"/>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is another option but to create a bin or another endpoint and return an empty response like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response />
```

If you omit the `action` attribute you'll end up with a loop which is probably not what you're looking for.

> The 'action' attribute takes a relative or absolute URL as a value. When recording is finished Twilio will make a GET or POST request to this URL including the parameters below. If no 'action' is provided,  will default to requesting the current document's URL.
>
> After making this request, Twilio will continue the current call using the TwiML received in your response. Keep in mind that by default Twilio will re-request the current document's URL, which can lead to unwanted looping behavior if you're not careful. Any TwiML verbs occurring after a  are unreachable.

(https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record?code-sample=code-using-attributes-in-a-record-verb&code-language=output-twiml)

Comment: That's great! That fixed my problem immediately! I had the XML declaration but was missing the <Response />. Thank you very much!